# Fibonacci Sequence proof by induction

Tags: inequality, induction, fibonacci-numbers

Let $F_0, F_1, F_2, ..., F_n, ...$ be the Fibonacci sequence, defined by the recurrence $F_0 = F_1 = 1$ and $\forall n \in \Bbb{N},$ $F_{n+2} = F_{n+1} + F_n$. Give a proof by induction that $\forall n \in \Bbb{N},$ $$\sum_{i=0}^{n+2} \frac{F_i}{2^{2+i}} < 1.$$

I showed that the "base case" works i.e. for $n = 1$, I showed that $\sum_{i=0}^3 \frac{F_i}{2^{2+i}} = \frac{19}{32} < 1.$

After this, I know you must assume the inequality holds for all $n$ up to $k$ and then show it holds for $k +1$ but I am stuck here.

Comment: Evidently he means the second of those definitions; otherwise $\frac12$ is an upper bound.

Comment: @MarkFischler I edited the question to add more details. Could you clarify your comment?

Comment: You have $2^{2+i}$ in one place, $2^2+i$ in another. They are different. Which (if either) do you want?

Comment: It is more common to define $F_0=0$ and $F_1=F_2=1.$

Comment: @GerryMyerson/ I assumed that $2^2+i$ was a typo and edited it.

Comment: It is $2^{2+i}$

Comment: Does anyone have any hints to solve this? Some additional context: this is a first year intro to proofs course.

Comment: Why $n+2$? This is true even with $\sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{F_i}{2^{2+i}} < 1$

Comment: @Sil I don't know. The question was just given that way. Any tips or hints? I'm really having trouble figuring it out.

Comment: Not by induction (induction is generally bad when you want to compare inequality of form $f(n)<c$ with a constant $c$ (there is no reason why if $f(n)=0.999999$ should imply that $f(n+1)<1$ as well). This is usually resolved by proving stronger statement instead, something like $f(n)<c-\frac{1}{n}$, which in this case might be tricky to find. Without induction, there is quite an easy proof though, you can prove that the infinite sum $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{F_i}{2^{2+i}}=1$, and since individual terms are non-negative, the statement follows.

Comment: @Sil I see. Unfortunately we don't deal with infinite sums in this course so it would have to be by induction. I just can't see it, though. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using induction on the inequality directly is not helpful, because $f(n)<1$ does not say how close the $f(n)$ is to $1$, so there is no reason it should imply that $f(n+1)<1$. Similar inequalities are often solved by proving stronger statement, such as for example $f(n)=1-\frac{1}{n}$. See for example [Prove by induction $\sum \frac {1}{2^n} < 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448626/prove-by-induction-sum-frac-12n-1) .

With this in mind and by experimenting with small values of $n$, you might notice:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{1+2} \frac{F_i}{2^{2+i}} = \frac{19}{32} = 1-\frac{13}{32}=1-\frac{F_6}{32}\\
\sum_{i=0}^{2+2} \frac{F_i}{2^{2+i}} = \frac{43}{64} = 1-\frac{21}{64}=1-\frac{F_7}{64}\\
\sum_{i=0}^{3+2} \frac{F_i}{2^{2+i}} = \frac{94}{128} = 1-\frac{34}{128}=1-\frac{F_8}{128}
$$
so it is natural to conjecture 
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n+2}\frac{F_i}{2^{2+i}}=1-\frac{F_{n+5}}{2^{n+4}}.
$$
Now prove the equality by induction (which I claim is rather simple, you just need to use $F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_{n}$ in the induction step). Then the inequality follows trivially since $F_{n+5}/2^{n+4}$ is always a positive number.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to prove by induction that $$F_n=\frac{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^{n+1}-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{5}}$$ Your series is the sum of two geometric progressions.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how this will help prove the proposition?

Comment: You need to find the sum of two geometric progressions. It is easy.

Comment: I'm still confused. Also, how do you factor in the $\frac{1}{2^{2+i}}$ part into this?

Comment: One geometric progression has a common ratio  $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2 \cdot 2}$. The second geometric progression has a common ratio  $\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2 \cdot 2}$.