# Induction proof of a known harmonic sum

Tags: induction

I want to prove that $$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \dots + \frac{1}{2^n} \leq 1$$  only by induction!

I check for the first one, $\frac12 \leq 1 $ correct.
Then I assume for $n=k$ : $$\frac12 + \frac14 + \dots + \frac{1}{2^k} \leq 1$$
And Try and prove for $n=k+1$

$$\frac12 + \frac14 + \dots + \frac{1}{2^k} + \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} \leq 1$$
But I know that $$\frac12 + \frac14 + \dots + \frac{1}{2^k} \leq \frac12 + \frac14 + \dots + \frac{1}{2^k} + \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} \leq 1$$ and so:

But I am stuck, this tells me that the sum for $n=k+1$ is always $1$ , not $S \leq 1$ I am so confused, because I can't use the geometric series sum formula.. any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove by induction $\sum \frac {1}{2^n} < 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448626/prove-by-induction-sum-frac-12n-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac12 + \frac14 + \dots + \frac{1}{2^k} + \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} \leq 1 \iff \frac14 + \dots + \frac{1}{2^k} + \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} \leq \frac12 \iff \frac12 + \dots + \frac{1}{2^{k-1}} + \frac{1}{2^{k}} \leq 1$.

The last step is multiplying by $2$.

Comment: +1 though I would start on the right hand side

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :** Prove the following stronger hypothesis induction :
$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \dots + \frac{1}{2^n} = 1 - \frac{1}{2^n}$$

Comment: There is a typo for $\le$.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: I mean to prove $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \dots + \frac{1}{2^n} \le 1 - \frac{1}{2^n}$ but maybe you are referring to the equality.

Comment: Proving the equality is sufficient if you want to prove the inequality...

Comment: Yes of course, that's fine also!

Answer (score 1):

We can instead try to prove the following

$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \dots + \frac{1}{2^n} \leq 1-\frac1{2^n}\le 1$$

then the induction step becomes

$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \dots + \frac{1}{2^n}+ \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \le 1-\frac1{2^n}+ \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}=  1-\frac1{2^n}\left(1- \frac{1}{2}\right)=1-\frac1{2^{n+1}}$$

and we are done.

Comment: Gio's proof does not count as induction? (I am curious)

Comment: @StackOMeow Indeed it doesn't seem a classical proof by induction but it contains the induction step $P(k) \implies P(k+1)$ then I think we can consider it fine.

Comment: Not new: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1448629/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, it is very similar, indeed my idea was use inequality. User TheSilverDoe used the same idea with equality.