# Sum of infinite series of fractions with powers of 2 in denominators

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic, divergent-series

$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^n}<1$$
How can I show this holds? I have tried adding couple of terms in photomath and it seems to hold, cannot prove it tho

Comment: Do you know sum of terms of G.P. ?

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1448626/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3837387/42969

Comment: This is a geometric series... To compute it, let $S_n = (x^0+x^1+x^2+\ldots +x^n)$. Then compute $(1-x)S_n$ to get $(1-x)S_n=(1-x^{n+1})$ and finally replace $x$ with $1/2$ to conclude.

Comment: You can prove this by induction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove by induction $\sum \frac {1}{2^n} <1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448626/prove-by-induction-sum-frac-12n-1)

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no $n$ on the right side,
there is no way to induct.

What you can do is show
by induction that
$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^n}
=1-\frac1{2^n}
$
from which the conclusion
immediately follows.